# Btitle is repeating more than once in an Oracle reporting

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting

I was making a report like this:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
TTITLE CENTER 'Test_Repo' SKIP 1 -
CENTER ==================== SKIP 1 LEFT 'Report' -
RIGHT 'Data: &_DATE' SKIP 2
BTitle Center 'End of Report' SKIP 2 -
       left 'end of date: &_DATE' -

drop table if exists 'Test_Repo';

create table Test_Repo nologging pctfree 0 parallel as
select id, status from table_1 where order like '721044%';

spool /tests/report.csv;

select ID || ';' || STATUS as "ID;STATUS" from Test_Repo;

spool off;

EXIT;
```

The output is putting more than one tittle in each csv file.

Can any one help me?

Comment: This isn't all valid Oracle syntax... not sure how it's not erroring ...

Comment: Hi.This is working but with more than one tittle

Comment: The `drop table if exists` is not valid, and if it was the table name you supplied is mixed case. The ORA-00933 error that would generate, and presumably the table-already-exists error from the `create`, won't be in the spooled file but would display in the terminal. Really not sure why you'd create a new table in here anyway, rather than just have your report query against `table_1` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get more than one set of titles if your report spans more than one page. The default page size is only 24, so if you get more than a handful of rows you'll see the titles repeated. You can `set pagesize 0` to make the page size unlimited; but then you lose all of the headings and titles. Or you can `set pagesize <some big number>`, but if it's too big then you'll get blank lines between the data and the bottom title.

It's a bit odd to mix the plain-text report header elements with separated values format for the data, but if you really want to, you either have to pick a big number for the pagesize, or calculate it first with a substitution-variable trick:

```
set termout off
column x_pagesize new_value y_pagesize
select count(*) + 10 as x_pagesize
from (<your original query>);
set termout on

set pagesize &y_pagesize
```

... but that obviously involves running your query twice, which may be too expensive (or slow).

The only other approach I can think of is to `set pagesize 0` and then generate the titles manually yourself, using `lpad()` to work out the layout if you don't want to do it manually based on the line size (which defaults to 80):

```
set pagesize 0
set tab off
set verify off
set feedback off

define page_width=80

define title_1='Test_Repo'
define title_2='===================='
define title_3a='Report'
define title_3b='Data: '
define title_4='End of Report'
define title_5='end of date: '

spool /tests/report.csv;

prompt
select lpad(' ', round((&page_width - length('&title_1'))/2))
  || '&title_1' from dual;
select lpad(' ', round((&page_width - length('&title_2'))/2))
  || '&title_2' from dual;
select '&title_3a'
  || lpad(' ', &page_width - (length('&title_3a') + length('&title_3b') + 20))
  || '&title_3b' || to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
prompt

prompt ID;STATUS

select ID || ';' || STATUS as "ID;STATUS" from Test_Repo;

prompt
select lpad(' ', round((&page_width - length('&title_4'))/2))
  || '&title_4' from dual;
prompt
select '&title_5' || to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;

spool off;
```

The `prompt ID;STATUS` line gives your column headers, which also don't appear when the page size is zero.

That seems to generate the same fake ttitle and btitle as your original SQL*Plus commands.

You could also use `prompt` to display the titles, but to preserve the spacing you'd need to enclose them in quotes, which you might not want to see. Although it depends who or what is going to be viewing this, I suppose.

You might also want to `set trimout on`, or `set termout off`, and `set trimspool off`. But those are details...